# env variable with dot from docker-compose to kubernetes yaml

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, docker-compose

I've used kompose to transform a docker-compose file to a kubernetes yaml. 
However, I run into a problem for the environment parameters with a dot. Kompose translates this in the same name, but kubernetes isn't accepting a dot. Any suggestion? It looks to me as an array notation, but I can't figure out if and how this is supported for a kubernetes YAML.

The original part of the docker-compose file.

```
ui:
   image: reportportal/service-ui:3.2.4
   environment:
      - RP_SERVER.PORT=8080
      - RP_CONSUL.TAGS=urlprefix-/ui opts strip=/ui
      - RP_CONSUL.ADDRESS=registry:8500
   restart: always
```

Answer (score 1):

Support for dots in env variable names was added just a few weeks ago and is only available in k8s v1.8.0-alpha.2 and newer:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/48986